# HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate Coffeescript Calls

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, html5boilerplate

How can I write these JS calls in Coffeescript?

iPhone Scale Bug Fix

```
MBP.scaleFix();
```

Hide URL Bar

```
MBP.hideUrlBar();
```

Fast Buttons (only use this if you only target webkit browsers, we are still testing out cross-browser support)

```
new MBP.fastButton(document.getElementById('myBtn'), function() {alert("clicked")});
```

Autogrow textarea

```
new MBP.autogrow(document.getElementById('myTextarea'), 14); // 14 -- line height
```

https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/wiki/JavaScript-Helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mostly stay the same.

#### iPhone Scale Bug Fix

```
MBP.scaleFix()
```

#### Hide URL Bar

```
MBP.hideUrlBar()
```

#### Fast Buttons

```
new MBP.fastButton document.getElementById('myBtn'), -> alert "clicked"
```

#### Autogrow textarea

```
new MBP.autogrow document.getElementById('myTextarea'), 14
```

Comment: You sure that parenthesis is correct at the end of autogrow textarea?

Comment: try it yourself.  I added it for clarity to make it clear that myTextarea is an argument of getElementById and 14 is an argument of autogrow.